# Hibernate: Do you need to manually close with sessionFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have way too many threads being used. I keep running out of memory in my unit tests. Do I need to close my session if I'm using sessionFactory. Won't the commit below end the session?

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Transaction transaction = null;

  try 
  {
       transaction = session.beginTransaction();
       transaction.commit();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  { 
       if (transaction != null) 
       {
         transaction.rollback();
         throw e;
       }
  }  
  finally 
  { 
       //Is this close necessary?
       session.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't end the session. One session can  span any number of transactions. Close the session explicitly. BTW such things are clearly documented.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the CurrentSessionContext. The JTASessionContext does close the session when the transaction is committed/rollbacked, and the ThreadLocalSessionContext as well. The example in the documentation does NOT close the session. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged

Comment: yeah Marko, take that. This exactly why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

In yout catch, verify if the transaction isActive() too.